# How to define a nested resources for polymorphic models with different namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, namespaces

I am struggling with defining a route in routes.rb to work with nested resources while having a polymorphic association and models with different namespaces.

There are two controllers (I show important lines only):

/app/controllers/project/profile/likes_controller.rb

```
module Project
 module Profile
  class LikesController < Project::ApplicationController
   def toggle
    ...
   end
  end
 end
end
```

/app/controllers/project/place/profile/profiles_controller.rb

```
module Project
 module Place
  module Profile
   class ProfilesController < Project::ApplicationController
   ...
   end
  end
 end
end
```

... and two models, the first having a polymorphic association called **likeable**:

/app/models/project/profile/like.rb

```
module Project
 module Profile
  class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   belongs_to :likeable, :polymorphic => true
   ...
  end
 end
end
```

... and the second model being a **likeable**:

/app/models/project/place/base.rb

```
module Project
 module Place
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :likes, :as => :likeable, :class_name => "Project::Profile::Like", :dependent => :destroy

  end
 end
end
```

... and this is my route definition as is:

routes.rb

```
...
scope :module => "project" do

 scope :module => "place" do
  resources :places do
    collection do
      scope :module => "profile" do
        resources :profiles do
            resources :likes
        end
      end
    end
  end
 end

 scope :module => "profile" do
  resources :likes do
   collection do
    post :toggle
   end
  end
 end

end 
...
```

As we can see, resource **likes** is a nested resource of resource **places**.

**What I want to achieve?**

I want to have a path to the nested resource **place/likes**, which should point to:

`{:action=>"toggle", :controller=>"project/profile/likes"}`

and keep the id of the likeable, **place_id** in this case.

I tried the following:

`<%= button_to t(:user_likes), ([likeable, likeable.likes.new]), :action => 'toggle', ... %>`

but this results in the following path:

`project_place_profile_basis_project_profile_likes_path`

which is not correct. The correct path would be `project_profile_likes_path`.

The following routes are available (**rake routes**):

`profile_likes POST` 
`/places/profiles/:profile_id/likes(.:format)`                                              `{:action=>"index", :controller=>"porject/place/profile/likes"}`

and

`toggle_likes POST   /likes/toggle(.:format)`                                                                   `{:action=>"toggle", :controller=>"project/profile/likes"}`

Has anyone an idea how to get the path to the **controller => project/profile/likes** and **action => toggle**?

Comment: Have ever managed to solve this problem of yours? I have exactly the same, I have one Polymorphic Controller under ```/controllers``` folder, I have mapped it in ```routes.rb``` under another namespace (```Admin```) and while it works OK on the browser, the tests are failing because of ```ActionController::RoutingError```.

I guess it is most probably looking for the ```Controller``` under ```/controllers/admin``` rather than in ```/controllers```

Any ideas?

Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Basically, I think you should present your controller class like that: `class Project::Profile::LikesController < Project::ApplicationController`.
In that way, rails doesn't see it like a nested class.